# new XMLHttpRequest in IE9 causes a JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, webforms

happens only in IE9 (in firefox it works fine)
tried lowering the security settings to minimum.
i'm not sure about other versions of IE because i have 9 installed.

Environment: asp.net 3.5 webforms
scripting frameworks: Anthem.NET, jquery

the anthem script is trying to create an instance of XMLHttpRequest and fails
i tried just create it myself on the page and had the same error.
on the same project i've created a new html page and it worked fine.

so it might be some scripting collusion...

Anyone?

Here is the original code that fails (on line 3) taken from the Anthem.NET framework that runs on the system:

```
function Anthem_GetXMLHttpRequest() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  // <-- This passes as True! window.XMLHttpRequest is {...}
    return new XMLHttpRequest(); // <---- Fails here
} else {
    if (window.Anthem_XMLHttpRequestProgID) {
        return new ActiveXObject(window.Anthem_XMLHttpRequestProgID);
    } else {
        var progIDs = ["Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];
        for (var i = 0; i < progIDs.length; ++i) {
            var progID = progIDs[i];
            try {
                var x = new ActiveXObject(progID);
                window.Anthem_XMLHttpRequestProgID = progID;
                return x;
            } catch (e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
return null;
```

}

here's the Window.XMLHttpRequest value:
[image]

and here is a picture of the failure that i created myself:
[image]

**Update:**
Just found out that it works in Compatibility Mode ! and when i go back to normal mode it works again!
BTW: the document mode is on Quirks mode (which is the default)

Comment: i cant start but it will never end... lot's of scripts in this page... my question is how can u get to this kind of situation that your browser can't new a XMLHttpRequest object?

Comment: what is the value of `window.XmlHttpRequest` (if you inspect it or print it to the console?)

Comment: the value is {...]here's the console:
window.XMLHttpRequest
{...}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I ran into the problem and I found that if I place the code which creates the XMLHttpRequest inside of a function that runs once the window loads that it works fine every time.  Try placing your code in this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var lala = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

Or if you use jquery:

```
$(function() {
    var lala = new XMLHttpRequest();
});
```

Comment: hi ryan. it's been a while and i dont have that code to test if your solution works. still, i'd like to mark a correct answer for this question. can you approve that this code fixed the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In IE (< v.9 )`window#XMLHttpRequest` is `undefined` as this is a browser specific global `Object` (i.e. for W3C conformant browsers such as the Mozilla or Webkit based browsers as well as Opera).

I don't really understand myself why

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
```

does not evaluate to `false` but well nothing you can do there.

What you can do however is add a code fork before that to check for `window#ActiveXObject` (i.e. Internet Explorer)

```
if(!! window.ActiveXObject) { // same as typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined"
    /* use MSXML */
}
else if(!! window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    /* use XMLHttpRequest */
}
else throw Error("Browser does not support XHR.") ;
```

---

If you cannot modify the source code at this point and the problem persists you might want want to change frameworks.

---

**Edit**: I just now noticed that you were saying the problem shows up in IE 9. That should actually not be the case as IE 9 supports the `XMLHttpRequest` `Object`.

Comment: i dont want to touch the source code of anthem because it suppose to work fine but i will if i have to...
i've edited the question and added some details about the state of window.XMLHttpRequest and some more debugging info...

Comment: @danfromisrael: So it is an empty `Object`? Great! Really weird. You are running this in a preview in Visual Studio, right? Maybe that's the real problem here (VS could be using IE < 9 for this). Whatever the case, the obvious work-around would be to use some other framework's XHR (XMLHttpRequest) wrapper.

Comment: vs2008 preview?
but i'm running it through IE9 & firefox...
when i hit run & debug (the green play button) it starts a local server and i can load the site from any browser just by copy & pasting the locahost address...
could VS2008 influence ie9 in a way ?

I thought the IE9 definitions might be blocking the javascript abilities but all security definitions are set to the lowest...

Comment: I was guessing that this must be some kind of preview function as the alert box is entitled "Microsoft Visual Studio" (not "Microsoft Internet Explorer"). How VS works internally, that I don't know.

Comment: Have you unchecked "standards mode" in the IE settings btw?

Comment: you're right... i pressed the Compatibility mode and it works fine!
and then when i go back to normal mode it's also works !
What could it be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6033/discussion-between-fk82-and-danfromisrael)

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, ie9 **DOES NOT** actually support XMLHttpRequest (you can change some settings in your internet options as the end-user, but I'm sure that's not gonna be an acceptable answer to your boss).

For ie9, you gotta do this:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (ie9)
{
    xmlhttp=new XDomainRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

Then, where you'll normally apply (for regular browsers):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
          // do your thing
     }
};
```

You'll have to do this instead (for ie9):

```
if (this.ie9)
{
     xmlhttp.onload = function()
     {
         // do your ie9 thing
     };
}
```